# Filesys::SmbClientParser get

Tags: perl

I'm able to use the [`Filesys::SmbClientParser`](https://metacpan.org/release/Filesys-SmbClientParser) module to put and get to a sharepoint, but I can't seem to `get` to a local directory.  The manual page says:

```
get($file, $target, [$dir])
```

What is `'$target'`?  If I don't specify the target and just the file and dir, it does get the file, but places it in the directory I'm running the script from.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing  the expected  behavior  - `get` mimics the command of the same name available  in the `smbclient` interface (which mimics olde fashioned `ftp` ). If you give a name to `$target` the file will be stored there, otherwise the default target is a file of the same name which will be written  to your `$CWD`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work, but the target must contain a file name, it just can't contain the path of the directory you want to place it.

$smb->get($report,"$pathto/$report");